# Windows Form crashes when VS is switched to designer view

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am using VS VS 2010. Whenever i switch to designer view, the form crashes. I have  not written any code in the form.It is at its default form! Still it crashes.Even when i add a new form it crashes. It works fine in code view. the designer view is giving me problems.

I know it is an already asked question.I have tried all of them.None of them worked.

I tried to 
 **Run VS in safe mode using cmd. It still crashes!**
**Then i unchecked Tools> Options > Debugging> unchecked Enabled just my code**

I tried many other things too.Still it crashes. How do i solve it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is about software, not programming. This question is more suitable for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). But you can always upgrade to VS 2017.

Comment: I just started as a trainee devoloper. Our project was done in VS 2010. As much as i want to upgrade, it is not my decision @VDWWD